# In Entity framework 4.0 how can we fetch multiple record set from database in one call & pass all data to View

Tags: entity-framework-4, dataset, multiple-resultsets

In Entity framework 4.0 how can we fetch multiple record set from database in one call like we do in ado.net dataset?

Soppose we have 3 table T1,T2 and T3. We need to fetch data from all tree table and pass to view(ASP.NET MVC3). **No JOIN** is to be used as all are independent table. Instead of making 3 call to database we want to wrap up all select statement in one SP and make only one call to database and pass all data to view.

In case of **dataset** if stored procedure return data from multiple select statement dataset populate each recordset in different table.

How can we achieve it in EF? Please help me.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box feature to batch queries in EF. But there are some efforts made by others to extend EF to support this.

- [Entity Framework Batch Update and Future Queries](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2011/11/29/entity-framework-batch-update-and-future-queries.aspx)
- [MultiQuery
  (more queries in one batch) in Entity Framework using LINQ](http://blog.cincura.net/232079-multiquery-more-queries-in-one-batch-in-entity-framework-using-linq/)